# Bluemix stage cancelled automatically

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a stage with two jobs (build and deploy) which is giving me a lot of trouble for the past 2 days.
Yesterday it started to fail about 1 every 4 times I run the stage. The stage is cancelled by itself. First I thought it might be a problem with my code but if I rerun the same execution it failed some of the times.

Today although, I haven't manage to complete a single run (I tried like 20 times in the last 3 hours). Some of the times the build job is cancelled, some others the deploy job.

Anybody facing the same problem? I cannot find where the issue is coming from...

Thanks!

Comment: How long does it run before it's cancelled?

Comment: If it's a long run, it might be related to Diego health checks.

Comment: just some seconds... it seems is working again. I guess they where doing maintenance tasks or something like that.

Comment: If you needed more of a verbose output, you could also try `CF_TRACE=true cf push myBluemixApp`